# Can I copy from vim to another window without +xterm-clipboard?

Tags: vim, copy-paste

I'm using Ubuntu and vim. I can copy text from vim and paste it into another window by highlighting it in vim, then middle-clicking in the other window. This works fine when I'm on my local machine.

I can also copy into the system register by highlighting text and yanking to the system register. (For example, `Shift-V JJ "+ y` to go into linewise visual mode, highlight two lines, select the '+' register and yank.) It's then available to paste into other windows.

However, if I ssh into my web host, I can't do either of these. (They use some flavor of Linux - I think it's CentOS.)

In vim, if I type `:version`, my local version shows `+xterm_clipboard`, but the host's version shows `-xterm_clipboard`. I don't have sudo rights there.

Is there any way to be able to copy from their vim without getting them to tinker with the installation?

Comment: worth noting if you have/had `+clipboard` and you should have put into your question that you are talking about SSH being involved. 'cos without that you seem to be  fine, so SSH / the SSH terminal you are using is crucial. It may barely  even be a VIM issue. (And since it has been almost 10 years, maybe you can post the solution)

Answer (score 1):

When you use ssh, you generally don't want the other computer to have access to your x session for security reasons.  But if you do an ssh -X (again, you should understand the security implications) I think it should allow the remote shell to access the x windows clipboard.

Comment: SSH is encrypted; wouldn't any clipboard contents transferred also be encrypted? If so, isn't it then just a question of whether I trust the machine on the other end?

Comment: @GorillaSandwich, pretty much yes--trusting another machine can be tricky and dangerous.  If you do anything sensitive, or if the sysadmin of the destination machine isn't security-aware, then your risk increases.  Basically, the remote machine can run anything (including a keylogger) on your x session.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run xcutset on their system ? That should be able to solve your problem. xclipboard is another option.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `mouse` setting in `vim` :

```
:set mouse
```

From `:help mouse` :

> When enabling the mouse in a terminal, copy/paste will use the
>           "* register if there is access to an X-server.  The xterm handling of
>           the mouse buttons can still be used by keeping the shift key pressed.

In practice, if set to `i` or `a`, copypasting using the middle mouse button won't work, *unless* you keep the `shift` key pressed (but the `shift` key trick seems to work only from local to remote, not the other way round).  If the `mouse` option is set to `n`, `v`, `c` or `r`, middle-button copypasting will work as intended (each option having other effects, obviously).

Therefore this `vim` command may fix your issue if you don't have other special mouse needs :

```
:set mouse=n
```

Note that `mouse=n` will also enable right-click paste.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you might use scp to open the remote file in your local vim. Then do the cut and paste within the local vim. Here is the syntax:

`:e scp://user@host//path/file.txt`