# How can I copy and paste text out of a remote vim to a local vim?

Tags: ssh, vim, copy-paste

I'm editing a file in vim on a remote machine via ssh and I want to copy text out of the remote file and paste it into a vim instance running on my local machine.  Is there an easy way to do this?  I can use my terminal emulator's selection features to select text that is currently on the screen, but if my selection is larger than can fit on the screen, I'm out of luck.

Comment: Check if [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1327771/127425) helps.

Answer (score 26):

Open the remote file *in* the local vim session:

```
  :e scp://user@host/relative/path/from/home.txt
```

Comment: I like. Nice and simple.

Comment: Great tip! Can this `scp://` be recognize elsewhere or it is VIM only?

Comment: @FrozenFlame: I believe it is app specific. BUT I wouldn't be surprised if a large DE like KDE or Gnome mandated support for this schema in every app.

Comment: For absolute paths: `:e scp://user@host//tmp/file.txt`

Answer (score 10):

If you have sufficient permissions on the remote machine, you can add

```
AcceptEnv WINDOWID
```

to /etc/ssh/sshd_config and restart sshd with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

Then on your local machine add

```
ForwardX11 yes
SendEnv WINDOWID
```

to your ~/.ssh/config file

Then by running an X-aware vim on the remote machine (e.g., `gvim -v`), you can copy and paste to and from the X clipboard. Just visually select the text (e.g., using `V`) and yank it into the `*` register.

**Edit**

I forgot to include the part about setting `SendEnv WINDOWID` in your ~/.ssh/config, so I added that and moved the enabling of X forwarding from the command line (ssh `-X` option) to the ~/.ssh/config file (`ForwardX11 yes`).

Comment: I needed to install the xauth package for this to work on Debian.

Comment: with this I can copy locally, and paste remotely. Is there a way to do also the other way around? thanks!